# Telerik RadGridView self-referencing hierarchy filtering, winforms

Tags: telerik, self-reference, radgridview

What is the best practice for improving the performance of the data filtering in RadGridView with self-referencing hierarchy? It takes a lot of time for a big amount of data or it throws the StackOverflowException. I am using `Grid.MasterTemplate.Relations.AddSelfReference(Grid.MasterTemplate, "_currentNo", "_prevNo");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Need to expand all nodes before filtering. It works with expand, collapse, then filter if you want to display data collapsed. The filtering process is almost instantly.